# TYPO3 4.5.x set default pivar to fe_user uid

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I have a page running TYPO3 4.5.x that has a singleview of a plugin (plugin.tx_browser). I would like the default pivar showUid to be the uid of the currently logged in user.

I can get the uid in typoscript with

```
data = TSFE:fe_user|user|uid
```

And I know I can set the piVar to a fixed value with

```
plugin.tx_browser_pi1._DEFAULT_PI_VARS.showUid = 575
```

but i can not set

```
plugin.tx_browser_pi1._DEFAULT_PI_VARS.showUid.data = TSFE:fe_user|user|uid
```

Is there a way to set the pivar thorugh typoscript dynamically?

The suggestion to use the stdWrap property unfortunately does not seem to work prior to TYPO3 6.2

Thanks

Comment: for nwo i went with a very long list of conditions - does the trick but is probably not very performant ...

Answer (score 0):

It's possible since Version 6.2. You just need to add the stdWrap property:

```
plugin.tx_browser_pi1._DEFAULT_PI_VARS.showUid.stdWrap.data = TSFE:fe_user|user|uid
```

See the the corresponding part in the [TypoScript Reference](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Setup/Plugin/Index.html#default-pi-vars-pivar-key).

Comment: unfortunately i forgot to mention that i run 4.5.x, an update is unfortunately out of the question  ... any ideas there?